# Fuzzy match column to column

Tags: sql, match, fuzzy

I'm trying to find a way to match a column of clean data in table 1 to a column of dirty data in table2 without making any changes to the dirty data.  I was thinking a fuzzy match, but there are too many entries in the clean table to allow for CDEs to be used. So, for example:

```
Table 1
GroupID    CompanyName
123        CompanyA
445        CompanyB
556        CompanyC

Table 2
GroupID    Patientname
AE123789   PatientA
123987     PatientB
445111     PatientC
```

And I'm trying to match the insurance company to the patient using the group number.  Is there a matching method out there? (Fortunately the group numbers are actually much longer and when looking for a single group's worth of patients, fuzzy matching works really well, so they seem to be unique enough to be applied here).

Working in SQL server 2008.

Comment: What kind of fuzziness do you expect? I'd suppose that `table_2.GroupID` should end with a value of `table_1.GroupID`.

Comment: It's occurring to me that I'm perhaps using match and join interchangeably, which is wrong and confusing to others.  I need the final table to be Table2.PatientName, Table1.Company name.  So in a perfect world, I'd be able to do something like: Join table2 on table1.groupid like table2.%groupid% but that isn't a real syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This changes slightly depending on which database you are using, but it looks like you're looking for something like this:

MSSQL

```
select *
from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t2.groupid like '%'+cast(t1.groupid as varchar(max))+'%'
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a747/2)

MySQL - use `Concat()`:

```
select *
from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t2.groupid like concat('%',t1.groupid,'%')
```

Comment: @user3629815 -- np, glad I could help.